# Make a div fill the space

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put two columns on the side of the content div. The part I have problems with is that I want the columns being built from 3 parts. The top and bottom should have fixed heights, but the middle one would adjust depending on the content height. Look at the sample with one column:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
          * { border: 1px solid black;}
          #contentWrapper     { width:450px; }
          #leftColumn         { width:100px; float: left; }
          #leftColumnTop      { width:100px; height:50px; 
                                 background-color: gray; }
          #leftColumnMiddle   { background-color: red; }
          #leftColumnBottom   { width: 100px; height:50px; 
                                 background-color: gray; }
          #content            { width: 300px; float: left; }
          #footer             { width: 400px; clear: both; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="contentWrapper">
       <div id="leftColumn">
      <div id="leftColumnTop"> </div>
      <div id="leftColumnMiddle"> </div>
      <div id="leftColumnBottom"> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">content<br> here <br>more 
               <br>more <br>more <br>more <br>more 
               <br>more <br>
          </div>
          <div id="footer">footer text</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

What I want is the `#leftColumnBottom` stick at the top of the footer and red `#leftColumnMiddle` to fill the space between top and bottom part.

Comment: Do you have to use fixed sizes?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how it can be made without fixed sizes. When using % of the a screen, images that will be set as backgrouds of those divs will create a very nice mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in everything except IE6; for that you'll need a conditional comment and css expression to set a height instead of `bottom` on `#leftColumnMiddle`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<style>* { border: 1px solid black;}
#contentWrapper     { position: relative; float:left; width: 450px; }
#leftColumnTop      { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 50px; left: 0; background-color: gray; }
#leftColumnMiddle   { position: absolute; width: 100px; top: 50px; bottom: 50px; left: 0; background-color: red; }
#leftColumnBottom   { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 50px; left: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: gray; }
#content            { width: 300px; float: left; margin-left: 100px;}
#footer             { width: 400px; clear: both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="leftColumnTop"> </div>
    <div id="leftColumnMiddle"> </div>
    <div id="leftColumnBottom"> </div>
    <div id="content">content<br>
    here<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And to the commenter - it nearly worked, so that's why. ;)

Comment: Just delete the damned answer, then =)

Comment: It seems to do the job, brilliant! Fortunately, I don't have to care about IE6 too much.

Answer (score 0):

try min-height for the one that needs to grow

Comment: In case anyone still cares about Internet Explorer 6, min-height isn't supported by it for divs. It appears to be fully supported by the newest versions of all the major browsers, though, so disregard this unless if you're a huge stickler for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both columns to be of equal height, *and* work in IE6, you basically have to hack.

A solution I've used in the past involves setting up a fake margin/padding for one of the columns. This assumes that you know a upper limit of how large the columns can grow (could be in the magnitude of several thousand px's).

This solution is outlined [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight).

Quoting from the page I linked:

> The basic method works like this:
>
> 1. Blocks which will act as columns must be wrapped in a container element
> 2. Apply overflow: hidden to the container element
> 3. Apply padding-bottom: $big_value [2] to the column blocks, where $big_value is a
>   large enough value to guarantee that it's equal to or larger than the tallest column
> 4. Apply margin-bottom: -$big_value to the column blocks