# How to extend a div to match 100% of the parent container in CSS?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a div fill the space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507579/make-a-div-fill-the-space)

How can I make an inner div extend to 100% of the container size? Please consider the example below where I want .footer to be 100% of the actual .wrapper size (which is 500px due to the .content inner element that has a width of 500px).

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .wrapper {
        width: 300px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .content {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .footer {
        background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">PAGE CONTENT</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER (should be 100%)</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6at8Q/ and scroll right you will see that the grey bar will not extend.

Comment: Also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314993/div-fill-parent-container

Comment: divs are by default 100% of the width of their parents.

Comment: Also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675107/make-a-div-fill-the-whole-page-in-height

Comment: The footer _is_ 100% the width of it's parent (300px). You've set the `.content` div to be 500px. Why can't you just set the footer to be 500px wide, or set the wrapper's width to be 500px? I really can't see where you'd put this CSS in a user-friendly layout.

Comment: I cannot hard code the width for .footer because the .content div will be adjusted dynamically.

Comment: @JohnFx "Make a div fill the space" is not what I'm interested - my problem is related to the "overflow: auto" rule.

Answer (score 1):

The `.wrapper` is 300px, and `.footer` is a child of `.wrapper`. By default this will mean that the `.footer` is 300px. You have made your `.content` `div` 500px wide which is extending the `.wrapper`. Make the wrapper 500px or distinguish what width you actually want your content to be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the content to be 300px with overflow: auto. Therefore it can have a child with width larger than 300px and this will cause the scrollbars to appear. In this situation I would like for all the other children to extend to the maximum available width (including the horizontal scroll).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS alone. Can you not make it just so that `.content` overflows and the rest stay as is? Otherwise you may need JS to accomplish this.

Comment: In your case, the children _are_ extending the maximum width available. The key note there is **available**. A child is limited by it's parent. Without explicitly setting the width greater than 100% it will not reach any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
   background-color: grey;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Beside this you should also edit your `.wrapper` class for perfection.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this in the JSFiddle posted. It doesn't work. Please check your answer before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be changed like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .wrapper {
        width: 500px; /* <~~ This is changed from 300 to 500px */
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .content {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .footer {
        /* width: 100%; <~~ You can add This line, but its not important, because a div tag always is 100% of its parent width */
        background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">PAGE CONTENT</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER (should be 100%)</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can Do this:

```
    .wrapper {
        /* width: 500px; <~~ Delete This line */
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .content {
       /* width: 500px; <~~ Delete This line too */
        background-color: green;
    }
    .footer {
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

Then the `.wrapper` div extends to the page width (100% of body).

Answer (score -1):

I've edited your fiddle check out http://jsfiddle.net/mAqJC/

Edit the width of the wrapper and everything should follow

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this solution does not work for me because I need the scrollbars. The maximum width should be 300px and the rest of the content should be visible after scrolling.