# height 100% overlapping parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill my page with a white background by extending my `div` to the bottom of the page. I've set my `html`, `body` and `div` to a `height` of 100%, but while the `html` and `body's` height extend perfectly to the bottom of the screen, my `div's` height goes even below that.

It seems like it's adding the height of my previous `div's` to the last div and thus extending it below my screen. Does anyone know how I can fix this so my last div extends to the bottom of my screen?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav id="nav"></nav>
        <header class="header"></header>
        <div class="categories"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my html. I want the content class to extend to the bottom of my screen because there's not enough content in there to fill it itself. I've given the html, body, app and content a height: 100%, but while the first 3 fill the screen perfectly, the content class goes even below the screen.

Comment: You can refer to another answer posted here, it might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214541/how-to-extend-a-div-to-match-100-of-the-parent-container-in-css

Comment: Please provide some code so it is fully understood what is going on!

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: can you post your css?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
overflow: auto
```

Would be nice to have some code example so we can help more.

Comment: You could add the css too, so we can have the complete overview of the situation. Also, the empty divs will generate no height.